# Make DataTable wider

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to expand this table because I think this table is too narrow.
This is an actual screenshot of the image.

[image]

and this is my code:

```
$('#month-auto-depo').DataTable({
      "columns" : [
        {"width": "30%"},
        {"width": null}
      ],
      "searching": false,
      "paging"   : false,
      "ordering" : false,
      dom        : 'Bfrtip',
      buttons    : [
        'csv', 'excel',
      ],
      "scrollX"  : true
});
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: Do you mind adding the `html` code for the `table` itself?

Comment: And you should have simple snippet code

Comment: I can't, Stack Overflow prevent me to post too much codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable document (https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html) said:

> Often you may want to have your table resize dynamically with the
>   page. Typically this is done by assigning width:100% in your CSS, but
>   this presents a problem for Javascript since it can be very hard to
>   get that relative size rather than the absolute pixels. As such, if
>   you apply the width attribute to the HTML table tag or inline width
>   style (style="width:100%"), it will be used as the width for the table
>   (overruling any CSS styles).

So you should set the container contain data table with your `width`, and data table set **inline style** `style="width:100%"` such as

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
```

It is enough smart (flexible) to change the table size when window change

Example with container width 80%:

```
div.container {
        width: 80%;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `Width:100%` or anything you want on your table tag.

```
<table class="datatable table" style="width:100%">
```